# Translate JS for Python on Android

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to get a javascript generated href from "dlbutton" only with python and bs4. I don't can use a heavy javascript parser because I'm on Android.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 2;
    var b = 413132;
    document.getElementById('dlbutton').href = "/n/abc/"+(n + n * 2 + b)+"3/6775808test.txt";
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas to achieve that?

In python I like to have this processed

```
n = 2;
b = 413132;

test = "/n/abc/"+str(n + n * 2 + b)+"3/6775808test.txt";

print test
#output /n/abc/4131383/6775808test.txt
```

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: oh sorry watch my edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the script tag using bs4 you could regex and then exec/eval the code:

```
import re


h = """<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 2;
    var b = 413132;
    document.getElementById('dlbutton').href = "/n/abc/"+(n + n * 2 + b)+"3/6775808test.txt";
    }
</script>"""
var = re.findall("(?<=var)\s+(.*)", h)
exp = re.search("(?<=\+)\(.*\)", h).group()
href = re.search("(?<=\.href)\s+\=(.*);", h).group(1).replace(exp, "str{}".format(exp))

for v in var:
    exec v

url = eval(href)
print(url)
```

Comment: No worries, in general be careful using eval.